# Removing items from a Bukkit Inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have a ItemStack, and I am trying to remove it from a player.
I tried this successfully before, but now; I have no luck. I tried:

```
player.remove(new ItemStack(Material.COAL, 2));
```

And I have also tried to do this:

```
ItemStack itemStack = new ItemStack(Material.COAL);
player.remove(itemStack);
```

Comment: I just want to remove 2 coal from a coal stack inside of the player's inventory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution and this static method does it wonderfully.

```
public static void removeInventoryItems(PlayerInventory inv, Material type, int amount) {
    for (ItemStack is : inv.getContents()) {
        if (is != null && is.getType() == type) {
            int newamount = is.getAmount() - amount;
            if (newamount > 0) {
                is.setAmount(newamount);
                break;
            } else {
                inv.remove(is);
                amount = -newamount;
                if (amount == 0) break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.COAL, 2);
player.getInventory().removeItem(i);
```

Yep, it's that simple

Comment: Well, then you should have told us that instead of player.remove(i). Because that is just wrong